# Multiple files input materialize

Tags: php, jquery, materialize

I need to upload multiple files, I'm using [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/), and it gives you the option to upload multiple files in one input:

```
<div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
        <div class="file-field input-field">
            <div class="btn">
                <span>Browse</span>
                <input type="file" multiple>
            </div>
            <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                <input type="text" name="pictures" class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload multiple files">
            </div>
        </div>    
    </form>
</div>
```

**materialize.js** does the following with this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.file-field input[type="file"]', function () {
    var file_field = $(this).closest('.file-field');
    var path_input = file_field.find('input.file-path');
    var files      = $(this)[0].files;      
    var file_names = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        file_names.push(files[i].name);
    }
    path_input.val(file_names.join(", "));
    path_input.trigger('change');
});
```

So, by `$_POST` I can only get the names of the files I want to upload. I need the full path of the files to upload them in my server.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: You can’t get these paths; it would violate the user’s privacy.

Comment: Ouch! Thanks @bfontaine

Comment: No file system would be safe if that was possible.

Comment: @bfontaine Please repost your comment as an answer (maybe with a little expansion).

Comment: @DaveP I just did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t get theses paths; it would violate the user’s privacy.

The File API spec says that about the `name` attribute (emphasis mine):

> The name of the file; on getting, this must return the name of the file as a string. There are numerous file name variations and conventions used by different underlying OS file systems; **this is merely the name of the file, without path information.**